# Confusion Regarding ! Character in Sed

Tags: bash, sed

These two sed commands appear to behave identically:

```
$ sed "s/^replace=*/replace=mytest/g" test.txt 

$ sed "
  s!^replace=*!replace=mytest!g
" test.txt
```

Why is this? Can the `!` character be used instead of `/`? I do not see that much explanation of `!` character in the sed documentation.

Comment: are you sure it is `!` not a `|` (pipe) ?

Comment: I am sure it is ! and not a pipe.

Comment: be careful with quotation, `bash`, for example, interprets `!`

Comment: be _very_ careful with quoting bangs, as I recall `zsh` interprets `!` even in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read man-pages more closely :)

[`info sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command):

> **3.5 The s Command**
>
> The syntax of the s (as in substitute) command is ‘s/regexp/replacement/flags’. The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given s command. The / character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can appear in the regexp or replacement only if it is preceded by a \ character.

tl;dr

As mentioned in these man-pages, You can use ANY single character as a separator for sed `regexp` and `replacement`.

EDIT:
Thanks [Evil Otto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796950/evil-otto) for crystal clearing it up :)

Comment: @Nashid, it might be ANY single character instead of '/' or '!' :)

Comment: technically, that part of the manual describes how you can address with pattern matching, and has nothing to do with the search-replace functionality/syntax.

Comment: the info page is a bit clearer on it:  *The syntax of the 's' (as in substitute) command is
's/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS'.  The '/' characters may be uniformly
replaced by any other single character within any given 's' command.*